# Gas leaking out of my brand new Icebear scooter

Tags: leak, gasoline, scooter

Went for a ride on my icebear scooter. Not even 12miles put on it and parked for the night. This morning gas is leaking out all over. It still starts but can not determine where on the engine it is leaking out.

Comment: Brand new == there probably is some kind of warranty and using that is better than expecting a random forum on the Internet to help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If this is a brand new scooter, is there any type of warranty on it where you might be able to take it back to the seller to get it fixed?

Comment: Did you fill the gas tank before you parked it?